# Check if a MySQL field value is equal to a certain number

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new with PHP and MySql and I've searched all over the Internet but couldn't find a proper answer.

Using PHP, I need to grab a value from a single cell of a MySQL Database and check if that value is equal to 0 or to 1.  If it's equal to 1 then set it to 0, and viceversa.

How do I do it?  Thank you for helping!!

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql_light = mysqli_query("SELECT light FROM bot_command WHERE cmd_id = '1'");
$result_light = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_light);

if (isset($result_light['light']) && $row['light'] == 1) {
    $sql = "UPDATE bot_command SET light='0' WHERE cmd_id = '1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result_select->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " - Light: " . $row["light"]."<br>";       
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}




if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo " - Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo " - Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

//$sql = "SELECT light FROM bot_command WHERE cmd_id = '1'";

?>
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` which don't mix together.

Comment: ...meaning, change that to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Thank you very much, just corrected!  Yeah, this is due to the new version of PHP, isn't it?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the `i` stands for "improved". So, did changing it to that fix your code?

Comment: Actually I preferred the solution by Flash Thunder: 

"UPDATE table SET value = ABS(value - 1)"

So I re-wrote the code and cleaned it all: so the PHP now it's simply 10 lines of code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET value = ABS(value - 1)
```

Simple, yet effective.

This will change all `1` to: `1 - 1 = 0` and all `0` to absolute value of: `0 - 1 = -1`, `ABS(-1) = 1`

Comment: Thank you!  Really effective, this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

There is an old trick to do it in one query:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `field` = 1 - `field`
```

This way if `field == 1` it will become `0`, and if it was `0` it will become `1`

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
UPDATE bot_command 
SET light=IF( light=1, 0, 1)
WHERE cmd_id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this:

```
$sql_light = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT light FROM bot_command WHERE cmd_id = '1'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_light)>0){
    $result_light = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_light);
    if($result_light['light']=="0"){
        $sql = "UPDATE bot_command SET light='1' WHERE cmd_id = '1'";
    }else{
        $sql = "UPDATE bot_command SET light='0' WHERE cmd_id = '1'";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    if($result){
         echo "Updated..";
    }else{
         echo "Not Updated..";
    }
}
```

Comment: I love the `ツ` in your nickname... even changed my keyboard layout to be able to write it from key :)

Comment: Thank you, but I had some errors with it: but I found the solution with the "UPDATE table SET value = ABS(value - 1)" code :D